# Why do I get that det(adj(A))=1?

Tags: linear-algebra

What am I doing wrong?
$det(adj(A))=det(A^{-1}det(A))=det(A^{-1})det(det(A))=det(A^{-1})det(A)=det(A^{-1}A)=det(I)=1$

Comment: If $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix then $\operatorname {det} (kB) =k^n\operatorname {det} (B) $. You have here $B=A^{-1}$ and $k=\operatorname{det} (A) $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are treating $\det A$ as a matrix, when it is a number.

Answer (score 3):

$\det(A)$ is a *scalar* not a matrix. And if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $c$ a scalar, we have $\det(cA) = c^n\det(A)$. So in this case, setting $c = \det(A)$, 
in your second equality you should have
$$\det( \det(A) A^{-1}) = \det(A)^n \det(A^{-1})$$
Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: whoops, I can proceed from here. Thank you!